# open android settings from QT app(com.android.settings)

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-settings, qtandroidextras

I have an android application in QT. 
I would like to call android settings from a button.

I used this code in Java :

```
public void usb(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent();  
    intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings");  
    startActivity(intent);  
}
```

Is there a way to call android settings using QT C++?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

QAndroidJniObject makes it possible to create JNI objects from Qt C++ code.

For example: to get the activity:

```
QAndroidJniObject activity =  QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");
```

For example: to create a new Intent:

```
QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent","()V");
```

You can then step by step translate execute your java code from C++....

To answer your specific question, just copy/paste this code:

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");   //activity is valid
if ( activity.isValid() )
{
    // Equivalent to Jave code: 'Intent intent = new Intent();'
    QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent","()V");
    if ( intent.isValid() )
    {
        QAndroidJniObject param1 = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("com.android.settings");
        QAndroidJniObject param2 = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings");

        if ( param1.isValid() && param2.isValid() )
        {
            // Equivalent to Jave code: 'intent.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.DevelopmentSettings");'
            intent.callObjectMethod("setClassName","(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;",param1.object<jobject>(),param2.object<jobject>());

            // Equivalent to Jave code: 'startActivity(intent);'
            activity.callObjectMethod("startActivity","(Landroid/content/Intent;)V",intent.object<jobject>());
        }
    }
}
```

...and then vote up! ;-)

Comment: Really helped...Thanks !
Would give a hundred upvotes if i can :)

Comment: Just create a hundred accounts ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer does not work with custom Android Settings Applications, and also failed on my new Android One phone, besides that, it opens on the Developer page.

Below is a working code (Qt 5.12) that opens the default settings appplication on first page and can easily be changed to open on other pages:

```
const QAndroidJniObject ACTION_SETTINGS = QAndroidJniObject::getStaticObjectField("android/provider/Settings",
                                                                                  "ACTION_SETTINGS",
                                                                                  "Ljava/lang/String;");
if (ACTION_SETTINGS.isValid()) {
    const QAndroidIntent intent(ACTION_SETTINGS.toString());
    QtAndroid::startActivity(intent.handle(), 10101);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can open details of specific application (by package id) in Application Manager using Qt:

```
QAndroidJniObject activity = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("org/qtproject/qt5/android/QtNative", "activity", "()Landroid/app/Activity;");   //activity is valid
if (activity.isValid())
{
    QAndroidJniObject param = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("package:com.example.mycoolapp");
    // Equivalent to Jave code: 'Uri uri = Uri::parse("...");'
    QAndroidJniObject uri = QAndroidJniObject::callStaticObjectMethod("android/net/Uri", "parse", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/net/Uri;", param.object<jstring>());
    if (!uri.isValid()) {
        qWarning("Unable to create Uri object");
        return;
    }
    QAndroidJniObject packageName = QAndroidJniObject::fromString("android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS");

    QAndroidJniObject intent("android/content/Intent","(Ljava/lang/String;)V", packageName.object<jstring>());
    if (!intent.isValid()) {
        qWarning("Unable to create Intent object");
        return;
    }
    intent.callObjectMethod("addCategory", "(Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/content/Intent;", QAndroidJniObject::fromString("android.intent.category.DEFAULT").object<jstring>());
    intent.callObjectMethod("setData", "(Landroid/net/Uri;)Landroid/content/Intent;", uri.object<jobject>());

    activity.callObjectMethod("startActivity","(Landroid/content/Intent;)V",intent.object<jobject>());
}
```