# Accessing Android Calendar Provider from QT / C++ Project

Tags: android, c++, qt, calendar, qandroidjniobject

Preferable way would be using Android Calendar Provider (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html). But this API is Java only.

I didnt found anything for the Android NDK Api to access Android Calendar.

Also QT 5 mobile api only lets you access Sensor / Location / Bluetooth and NFC data (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/mobiledevelopment.html).

Is there any way to query the Android phone calendar from a C++ / QT project?

Edit: I need future appointments the user has in his calendar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [QAndroidJniObject](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html), it makes it possible to create and use Android native SDK objects from a C++/Qt application.

If you have a working java code accessing the calendaryou can try to transcode it using QAndroidJniObject.

Here is an example: [open android settings from QT app(com.android.settings)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024615/open-android-settings-from-qt-appcom-android-settings)

Note : If the java code is too complex, you can also include a java file in your C++/Qt project and create an object from this java file using QAndroidJniObject. It may be easier than transcoding the whole code.